# What licence header to use for paid contributors pushing code for an open-source AGPL project?

Tags: agpl-3.0

If I hire someone to work on a soon to be opensource AGPL project with me what licence header should they use for the code committed by them?

Currently all files have the following header

```
Copyright (c) 2019 Hajime

This file is a part of {{ProjectName}}

{{ProjectName}} is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify ..... etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they create a "work for hire", then in most jurisdictions the copyrights are owned by the company or person that hired the programmer. It is their name that must appear in the copyright line and they get to dictate which license will be applied if and when they decide to publish the software (which includes running it on a public-facing server in case of the AGPL).

So, to answer your question more directly: You tell them what license header to use and it can very well be the one you have been using so far.

This does not give them any rights to the code, because they did not receive the code under the AGPL terms.